# Number of Stages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If we have a simple workflow as mentioned here ([https://ianwhitestone.work/spark-web-ui/#:~:text=And%20in%20PySpark%2C%20the%20code%20would%20look%20something%20like%3A](https://ianwhitestone.work/spark-web-ui/#:%7E:text=And%20in%20PySpark%2C%20the%20code%20would%20look%20something%20like%3A))  having 2 datasets (one sales transaction and another shop dimension), group by shop and compute total sales.

```
output = (
    trxns_skewed_df
    .join(shop_df, on='shop_id')
    .groupBy('shop_country_code', 'created_at_date')
    .agg(
        F.max('amount').alias('max_transaction_value')
    )
)

result = output.collect()
```

It was mentioned here ([https://ianwhitestone.work/spark-web-ui/#:~:text=Our%20job%20has%204%20stages](https://ianwhitestone.work/spark-web-ui/#:%7E:text=Our%20job%20has%204%20stages)) that this would create 4 stages.

- 1 stage each for the initial reading of each dataset
- 1 for the join
- 1 for the aggregation

**Question** - Given there would be shuffle only during join and group by/aggregation, why spark creates additional 2 stages during the read. Should not itbe just two due to two shuffles?